# Invalid type for array subscript error

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error with a piece of my code... In the following, "vertices" is defined as a vector of gVector3's, where gVector3 is a float array of length three (x,y,z coordinates of a point). The [] operator has been overloaded for the gVector3 class, so vertices[i][k] returns a float.

I have an error in this line: `(*result)[i+k] = vertices[i][k]`. The full code as well as the error message is below. Any insights would be appreciated!

```
float* Polygon::getVertices(){
    float* result = new float[vertices.size()*3];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            (*result)[i+k] = vertices[i][k];   // invalid types for array subscript
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `result` is declared as `float*`, `(*result)` is just a `float`. It's not an array, so you can't subscript it. The assignment should be:

```
result[3*i + k] = vertices[i][k];
```

or:

```
*(result + 3*i + k) = vertices[i][k];
```

Notice that you also need to multiply `i` by 3, otherwise you're going to repeatedly overwrite the same elements of `result`. E.g. you'll write into `result[1]` when `i = 0, k = 1` and when `i = 1, k = 0`. This is called [*row major indexing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `result[3*i+k]` for `(*result)[i+k]`. `result` is a pointer to a float, not a pointer to a float array.

Comment: Exactly, change that to `result[i+k]`.

Answer (score 0):

`float* result = new float[vertices.size()*3];` is creating a pointer of float type. But in the nested for loop you tend to treat it as a pointer to array type hence the error. Either make the pointer an array  type, or use  `*(result + 3*i + k) = vertices[i][k];`